# how to solve this error of javascript program

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

```
TypeError: Salt must be a buffer
    at TypeError (native)
    at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:579:20)
    at Object.exports.pbkdf2Sync (crypto.js:570:10)
```

**This is the function:**

```
function hash (input, salt) {
    // How do we create a hash?
    var hashed = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(input, salt, 10000, 512, 'sha512');
    return ["pbkdf2", "10000", salt, hashed.toString('hex')].join('$');
}
```

**And this is how i am sending the arguments:**

```
var dbString = rows[0].password;
var salt = dbString.split('$')[2];//here i am taking the 2nd column value from a table with 3 columns
var hashedPassword = hash(new Buffer(password, 'binary'), salt); // then passing it to the function hash
```

Comment: Have you tried `new Buffer(salt, 'binary')`?

Comment: i tried this but its not removing the error.

Comment: Do not use titles of the form "need to solve this error". Almost all posts are about solving some error. Describe the error **in the title**. To solve your specific problem, try the time-honored approach of reading the error message, then reading it again, then reading it again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the error message: salt must be a `Buffer`.

Throw it in to `Buffer()`, I don't know the details, but based on the code you wrote, it should be something like this:

```
return ["pbkdf2", "10000", new Buffer(salt, 'binary'), hashed.toString('hex')].join('$');
```

Comment: What's the point of an "answer" which says to do what the error message says?

Comment: @torazaburo what's the point of a "question" which can be simply solved by following the error message?

Comment: There is none. Which is why it should be downvoted and/or closed.